# ut8 Wordnet Lemmatizer - NLTK

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

I *just* got into trouble with Wordnet Lemmatizer within NLTK. When I say "just", I really mean so ^^ My Python script crashed (and I don't know) just 10 minutes ago. I hope I'm doing nothing wrong, well ... I hope you'll tell me!

That's the script :

```
sentence = """Hello, I am George."""

tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)

wordnet_lem = nltk.stem.WordNetLemmatizer()
for (word, pos) in tagged :
    wordnet_pos = get_wordnet_pos(pos)

    if wordnet_pos != False:
        couple = (wordnet_lem.lemmatize(word, pos=wordnet_pos))
    else :
        couple = (wordnet_lem.lemmatize(word), pos)
```

I got this error now :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\workspace\test.py", line 21, in <module>
    wordnet_pos = get_wordnet_pos(pos)
  File "C:\Users\user\workspace\test.py", line 9, in get_wordnet_pos
    return nltk.corpus.wordnet.NOUN
  File "C:\Python344\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\util.py", line 99, in __getattr__
    self.__load()
  File "C:\Python344\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\util.py", line 67, in __load
    corpus = self.__reader_cls(root, *self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "C:\Python344\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\reader\wordnet.py", line 1055, in __init__
    self._load_lemma_pos_offset_map()
  File "C:\Python344\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\reader\wordnet.py", line 1111, in _load_lemma_pos_offset_map
    for i, line in enumerate(self.open('index.%s' % suffix)):
  File "C:\Python344\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 1188, in __next__
    return self.next()
  File "C:\Python344\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 1181, in next
    line = self.readline()
  File "C:\Python344\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 1135, in readline
    new_chars = self._read(readsize)
  File "C:\Python344\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 1367, in _read
    chars, bytes_decoded = self._incr_decode(bytes)
  File "C:\Python344\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 1398, in _incr_decode
    return self.decode(bytes, 'strict')
  File "C:\Python344\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 18: invalid start byte
```

My first idea would be that my wordnet corpus got corrupted somehow. What do you think?

Thanks a lot for helping!

EDIT:

I am adding the definition of get_wordnet_pos:

```
def get_wordnet_pos(treebank_tag):
    if treebank_tag.startswith('J'):
        return nltk.corpus.wordnet.ADJ
    elif treebank_tag.startswith('V'):
        return nltk.corpus.wordnet.VERB
    elif treebank_tag.startswith('N'):
        return nltk.corpus.wordnet.NOUN
    elif treebank_tag.startswith('R'):
        return nltk.corpus.wordnet.ADV
    return False
```

Comment: Running your code does not elicit an error with me: a list of all couples is `['Hello', (',', ','), ('I', 'PRP'), 'be', 'George', ('.', '.')]`...

Comment: I posted the full code (same as above actually) but the formatting differs, there: http://pastebin.com/6GAQVMK4. Could you run it and tell me whether the problem is happening to you? :)

Comment: The error shows a `UnicodeDecodeError`, which is not a problem in your actual script: there is no utf-8-related reason for the script to freak out on your `sentence`. It is probably best to reinstall the Wordnet corpus, as you suggested yourself.

Comment: Everything works like a charm now, thank you! Now I'm going to look for why that happened on the server. Cheers! :)